# How can I fix the constructor in my Employee program?

Tags: java

I currently have an assignment in my coding class that has me stumped. I'm a beginner at coding, and I am currently trying to get a constructor to work. I get the following *error:
"constructor Employee in class Employee cannot be applied to given types;
required: String,int,double
found:    String
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length"*

Constructor code:

```java
public class Employee {
    
    String name; //Employee name
    int employeeId; // employee id
    double salary; // employee salary
    
    
   //Constructor here
    public Employee(String name, int employeeId, double salary) {
        this.name = name;
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
        this.salary = salary;
```

Problem corresponding code:

```java
Employee micheal = new Employee ("Micheal, 124, 15000.0");
        
Employee jim = new Employee ("Jim, 124, 10000.0");
```

The purpose of the program is to display two made up employee's names, ID #'s, and salary. After that's done, I need to have it calculate and set a 10% raise in salary for one of the employee's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your arguments are 1 String. Your constructor is looking for String, int, double. You just put the closing quotation mark in the wrong spot.

```
Employee micheal = new Employee ("Micheal, 124, 15000.0");
Employee jim = new Employee ("Jim, 124, 10000.0");
```

Should be

```
Employee micheal = new Employee("Micheal", 124, 15000.0);
Employee jim = new Employee("Jim", 124, 10000.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to respect typing in java *String* enclosed within quoted, *int* and *double* must be numbers not strings. So Change

```java
Employee micheal = new Employee ("Micheal, 124, 15000.0");
```

to :

```java
Employee micheal = new Employee ("Micheal", 124, 15000.0);
```